# How to Auto Sort Google Sheet by Date Using a Script

Tags: javascript, sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to run a script that will Auto Sort dates from most current to oldest within my Google Workbook by date.

For example:
Monday, Aug 30, 2019
Sunday, Aug 29, 2019
Wednesday, Aug 15, 2019
Saturday, Aug 12, 2019
Tuesday, July 31, 2019

I've found a script online that works great at sorting numerical data correctly but not dates.

Right now, the script (shown below) is sorting dates by grouping Months of the year or Days of the week together.

For example:
Tuesday, Aug 01, 2019 
Tuesday, July 15, 2019
Wednesday, Aug 14, 2019
Wednesday, Aug 07, 2019
Thursday, Aug 15, 2019
Friday, Aug 16, 2019
Friday, July 18, 2019
Monday, March 5, 2019

See script below...

Also, below is a link to a test sheet which will show you how I have formatted my sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AhjFE6jTAwKu4e6zS3fOADvJph0RcOhttgIv1vuAkks/edit?usp=sharing

You'll find 4 sheets at the bottom of the Worksheet.
1. Master Leads List
2. Brant
3. Kirsty
4. Bill

How it should work:

Step 1. From within the Master Leads Leads, a salesperson assigns their name to a customer

Step 2. The data associated with the customer is transferred to the Salesperson's personal sheet (I used Integromat to perform this task - similar to Zapier)

Step 3. Each time a Salesperson opens up their personal worksheet, or hits refresh, the newest customers according to the dates found in column B under "Date of Lead" should appear at the top of the sheet moving to down to the oldest.

To test how it is currently working:

Step 1. From within the Google Sheet, Tap on Master Leads List sheet
Step 2. Assign 6 customers with different dates to Brant: 2 Mondays- different dates, 2 Wednesdays- different dates, 2 Fridays- different dates
Step 3. Open Brant's personal sheet
Step 4. Tap the refresh button from within Brant's personal to trigger the auto sort
Step 5. Notice that the dates are sorted incorrectly - using grouping of Days.

Link to Test Google Sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AhjFE6jTAwKu4e6zS3fOADvJph0RcOhttgIv1vuAkks/edit?usp=sharing

Script exactly as is in script editor:

```
var SORT_COLUMN_INDEX = 2;
var ASCENDING = false;
var NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS = 1;

var activeSheet;

function autoSort(sheet) {
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();

  if (NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS > 0) {
    range = range.offset(NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS, 0);
  }

  // Perform the actual sort.
  range.sort( {
    column: SORT_COLUMN_INDEX,
    ascending: ASCENDING
  } );
}

function onEdit(event) {
  var editedCell;

  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  editedCell = activeSheet.getActiveCell();

  if (editedCell.getColumn() == SORT_COLUMN_INDEX) {
    autoSort(activeSheet);
  }
}

function onOpen(event) {
  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  autoSort(activeSheet);
}

function onInstall(event) {
  onOpen(event);
}
```

Any thoughts or feedback would be greatly appreciated as I've spent days on this :)

Comment: In your shared Spreadsheet, where is the refresh button in the sheet of `Brant Personal`? And when you want to sort with the column "B" on the sheet of `Brant Personal`, the values of column "B" is the string type. By this, I think that it seems that the sort doesn't correctly work. For example, when the values are put to the column "B", how about putting them as the date object? By the way, in your project of shared Spreadsheet, the same function names of `onEdit()` are been using.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike !

When I mean refresh, I just mean refresh the browser.

In regards to the Date Object, what would the data look like as Date Object?

Last, I'm not following on the same function names. Can you be more specific please :)

PS - I'm super inexperienced when it comes to scripts and coding. Your patience is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my incomplete comment. 1. In your shared Spreadsheet, the values of column "B" in the sheet `Brant Personal` are the string type. 2. When the script editor is opened on your shared Spreadsheet, you can see the script files of `Keep Data Sorted` and `Automatic Timestamp`. There are `onEdit` in each file. At Google Apps Script, in your case, only one of 2 `onEdit` functions is run. So I commented this.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks for the further input.

1. So if I'm not mistaken, because the values (Dates) in column B are string type, they are not sorting correctly? And your solution to this would be potentially to save the values as the Date Object? 

2. In regards to both script files of Keep Data Sorted and Automatic Timestamp being onEdit, what do you suggest I do so that both are running correctly?

Again, your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I cannot see the script that populates the salesperson sheet from the master sheet. The main problem is that during the population process the cell content with a valid data format `Tuesday, June 18, 2019 at 2:02 AM` is transformed to `Tuesday-June-18-2019 2:02 am` which is not recognized as a valid date format. PS: As to your question above, usually correctly formatted cell content will be automatically recognized as a date, but you can doublecheck/change it by highlighting a cell/range and clicking on the '123' button.